# How to add an option to select-all and deselect-all in vue element-UI with multi select having filter option?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am newbie in VueJs. I am trying to create a component that allow multiple select having search option and allow to select-all/deselect-all options.

I'm using vue-element-ui library to accomplish this, https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#basic-multiple-select.

I want to add first option in select-dropdown for such purpose.

I have tried something like this:

```
<template>
        <el-select
          v-model="selectTag.values"
          placeholder="select profiles"
          multiple
          collapse-tags
          filterable
          remote
          @change="values => handleSelectAll(values, 'routingProfile')"
          :filter-method="handleFilter"
        >
          <el-option
            v-for="option in selectTag.options"
            :key="option.value"
            :label="option.label"
            :value="option.value"
          >
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
</template>
<script>
import { Select, Option } from 'element-ui';

export default {
  props: {},
  components: {
    [Select.name]: Select,
    [Option.name]: Option
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectTag: {
        prvsState: [],
        loading: false,
        count: 0,
        values: [],
        options: [
          { value: 'all', label: 'SELECT/DESELECT ALL' },
          { value: 'value1', label: 'label1' },
          { value: 'value2', label: 'label2' }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
  handleFilter(query) {
  var searchQuery = query.toLowerCase();
  var formField = this.selectTag;
  var fieldOptions = formField.options;
  var filterOptions = [{ value: 'all', label: 'Select/unselect all' 
  }];
  fieldOptions.forEach(option => {
    let optionLabel = option.label.toLowerCase();
    if (optionLabel.includes(searchQuery)) {
      filterOptions.push(option);
    }
  });
  formField.options = filterOptions;
},
    handleSelectAll(selectedValues) {
      var fieldOptions = this.selectTag.options;
      var prvsState = this.selectTag.prvsState;
      if (selectedValues.includes('all')) {
        if (prvsState.includes('all')) {
          this.selectTag.values = [];
          this.selectTag.prvsState = [];
        } else {
          this.selectTag.prvsState = selectedValues;
          this.selectTag.values = [];
          fieldOptions.forEach(option => {
            if (option.value != 'all') {
              this.selectTag.values.push(option.value);
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.selectTag.values = selectedValues;
        this.selectTag.prvsState = selectedValues;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

It works fine if I disable filter option. It didn't work with search/filter option. Please let me know how to do this thing. Or please suggest some equivalent vueJs library for this task. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar situation so my solution was to make button "Select All" instead of "Select All" as an option. If you want to take my approach then you should call this method on button click:

```
handleSelectAll() {
    this.selectTag.values = [];
    for(let i=0; i < this.selectTag.options.length; i++) {
        this.selectTag.values.push(this.selectTag.options[i].value);
      }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener to the input, then check if the added value is your all option. Now you may change the binded value to all of the available:

```
<el-select @change="isAllLocations" style="margin-left:1rem;width:160px;" multiple v-model="filterLocations" placeholder="Locations">
    <el-option v-for="item in searchLocations" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
</el-select>


isAllLocations(a) {
    if(a[a.length-1] === 'All') {
        this.filterLocations = []
        this.searchLocations.forEach(loc => {
            if(loc.value !== 'All' ) {
                this.filterLocations.push(loc.value)
            }
        })
    }
}
```